# How do I order an array of strings on the basis of an array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have an array of integers with a bunch of numbers from 1-10
Then I have an array of names(strings) which belong with the numbers a.e.

```
Numbers[0] = 5, Numbers[1] = 2
Names[0] = "Jeremy", Names [1] = "Samantha".
```

I can easily order the numbers with:

```
    int n = sizeof(Numbers) / sizeof(Numbers[0]);
    sort(Numbers, Numbers + n, greater<int>());
```

But then the names and numbers don't match at all.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Use an array of `struct {int num, std::string name}` (or similar), rather than two separate arrays.

Comment: same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960042/sorting-one-array-based-on-another-in-place/

Answer (score 1):

A very common approach is to create an array of indices and sort that:

```
std::vector<int> indices(Numbers.size());
std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);
std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
          [&](int A, int B) -> bool {
              return Numbers[A] < Numbers[B];
          });
```

The original arrays are not altered, but now `indices` can be used to access both arrays in the desired order.

If we want to reorder `Numbers` or `Names` in place, then we can
create a set of "back indices" that record where to find the element i in the sorted array:

```
std::vector<int> back_indices(indices.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++)
    back_indices[indices[i]] = i;
```

Now we can reorder, for example, `Names` in place in the desired order:

```
int index = 0;
std::string name = Names[index];
for (int i = 0; i < back_indices.size(); i++) {
    index = back_indices[index];
    std::swap(name,Names[index]);
}
```

Comment: that's an excellent point that you don't actually have to reorder the arrays in many cases when it's sufficient to just access the arrays in a different predetermined index order. If you do however need to reorder the arrays, can you do it in-place using vector `indices`?

Comment: @PatrickParker Reordering the arrays in place based on the `indices` is difficult (i.e. boils down to resorting) unless you are willing to reorder the indices too -- once you permute one entry the array, now the indices are no longer correct. If you are willing to make a copy (i.e. not in place) then its trivial.

Comment: @PatrickParker Added a way to sort in place based on "back indices"

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this code which should give you the required behavior:

```
struct numberName {
    int num;
    string name;
};

bool compare(numberName a, numberName b){
    return a.num < b.num; // if equal, no need to sort.
}

int main() {
    numberName list[2];
    list[0].num = 5, list[1].num = 2;
    list[0].name = "Jeremy", list[1].name = "Samantha";
    sort(list, list+2, compare);
}
```

Like [HAL9000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9948091/hal9000) said, you want to use a struct since this keeps variables that belong to each other together. Alternatively you could use a pair, but I don't know if a pair would be good practice for your situation or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of the complexities introduced by using parallel arrays.

If you insist on keeping them as parallel arrays, here is a possible approach. Create a vector of integer indexes, initialised to { 0, 1, 2, 3, etc }. Each integer represents one position in your array. Sort your vector of indexes using a custom comparision function that uses the indexes to refer to array1 (Numbers). When finished you can use the sorted indexes to reorder array1 and array2 (Names).

One could also write their own sort algorithm that performs swaps on the extra array at the same time.

Or one could trick `std::sort` into sorting both arrays simultaneously by using a cleverly designed proxy. I will demonstrate that such a thing is possible, although the code below may be considered a simple hackish proof of concept.

**Tricking std::sort with a cleverly-designed proxy**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr size_t SZ = 2;
int Numbers[SZ] = {5, 2};
std::string Names[SZ] = {"Jeremy", "Samantha"};
int tempNumber;
std::string tempName;

class aproxy {
    public:
    const size_t index = 0;
    const bool isTemp = false;
    aproxy(size_t i) : index(i) {}
    aproxy() = delete;
    aproxy(const aproxy& b) : isTemp(true)
    {
        tempName = Names[b.index];
        tempNumber = Numbers[b.index];
    }
    void operator=(const aproxy& b) {
        if(b.isTemp) {
            Names[index] = tempName;
            Numbers[index] = tempNumber;
        } else {
            Names[index] = Names[b.index];
            Numbers[index] = Numbers[b.index];
        }
    }
    bool operator<(const aproxy& other) {
        return Numbers[index] < Numbers[other.index];
    }
};

int main() {
    aproxy toSort[SZ] = {0, 1};
    std::sort(toSort, toSort+SZ);
    for(int i=0; i<SZ; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Numbers[" << i << "]=" << Numbers[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Names[" << i << "]=" << Names[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

...and an even more cleverly-designed proxy could avoid entirely the need to allocate SZ "aproxy" elements.

**Tricking std::sort with an "even more cleverly-designed" proxy**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
class aproxy;

constexpr size_t SZ = 2;
int Numbers[SZ] = {5, 2};
std::string Names[SZ] = {"Jeremy", "Samantha"};
aproxy *tempProxyPtr = nullptr;
int tempNumber;
std::string tempName;

class aproxy {
    public:
    size_t index() const
    {
        return (this - reinterpret_cast<aproxy*>(Numbers));
    }
    bool isTemp() const
    {
        return (this == tempProxyPtr);
    }
    ~aproxy()
    {
        if(isTemp()) tempProxyPtr = nullptr;
    }
    aproxy() {}
    aproxy(const aproxy& b)
    {
        tempProxyPtr = this;
        tempName = Names[b.index()];
        tempNumber = Numbers[b.index()];
    }
    void operator=(const aproxy& b) {
        if(b.isTemp()) {
            Names[index()] = tempName;
            Numbers[index()] = tempNumber;
        } else {
            Names[index()] = Names[b.index()];
            Numbers[index()] = Numbers[b.index()];
        }
    }
    bool operator<(const aproxy& other) {
        return Numbers[index()] < Numbers[other.index()];
    }
};

int main() {
    aproxy* toSort = reinterpret_cast<aproxy*>(Numbers);
    std::sort(toSort, toSort+SZ);
    for(int i=0; i<SZ; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Numbers[" << i << "]=" << Numbers[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Names[" << i << "]=" << Names[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Disclaimer:* although my final example above may technically be in violation of the strict-aliasing rule (due to accessing the same space in memory as two different types), the underlying memory is only used for addressing space-- not modified-- and it does seems to work fine when I tested it. Also it relies entirely on `std::sort` being written in a certain way: using a single temp variable initialized via copy construction, single-threaded, etc. Putting together all these assumptions it may be a convenient trick but not very portable so use at your own risk.